# How to add a low-limit switch to a trupper hoist

Tags: motor, switches

I have a trupper hoist and I want to add a low limit switch, I've been trying to understand the wiring, I tried to add the switch between the B and 10, I also tried cutting the connection between A and B and leaving the switch, it still disables the up but if the switch is activated and I give it down, it disables the down.

My theory is that the capacitor should be connected between 7 and 10, to be between line and line, eliminate the terminal 5 and 11 and eliminate the connection e-a-b.
[image]